# Exported a map from an .MXD (ArcGIS) to .AI, why did some textboxes including '≤' come in as '='?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, typefaces, symbols

I will post the area in question below.

Here is the "before" of the legend in ArcGIS, an MXD file:
[image]

When I export the entire map to AI, it mostly comes into Illustrator just fine, but when I go to look at the textboxes from the legend, those less than or equal to signs have turned into equal signs, what's up with that?
[image]

I can change them just fine once I'm in Illustrator but it seems to happen every time with those symbols. Is there a setting I can make to fix this?

Comment: Are there any options during export to "Vectorize Bitmap or Picture Symbol Fills and/or Convert Marker Symbols to Polygons?" (terms taken fro a different GIS package)

Comment: What is the font you are using? It looks like it's assigning a new glyph to the ≤ because the parent font doesn't have it.

Comment: it is open sans condensed light. i have it in illustrator too.

Comment: also @Yorik, there is the "Vectorize layers with bitmap markers/fills". I tried exported with that setting turned on and it didn't change my issue...still getting equal signs. Seems that is related to picture symbols though, and this is text.

Comment: The Google font **Open Sans Condensed Light** includes the glyph for U+2264 _less-than or equal to_, so most probably the problem is not the font.

Comment: related? ( http://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000008341 )

Comment: I am wondering if U+2264 is a ligature , since ArcGIS seems to have problem with ligature embedding ( https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000010383 )

Comment: I checked it with a pair of font editors, and it seems U+2264 is not a ligature... I was thinking that perhaps the export process is messing with Unicode character values? Or maybe embedding the font in the exported document could help? I am not sure.

Comment: @Yorik funny enough your suggestion solved another issue I was having with stippling fill rasterizing within polygons when coming from GIS to Illustrator. That setting ensures the stippling is vectorized...so that was cool. :)

Comment: @PepeOchoa: I cannot think of how, without an intentional filter, the program would substitute U+003D for 2264. If it is {codepage entry}+offset, and the entry point is dropped leaving an identical offset  then it is an incredible coincidence that the glyphs are so close semantically.

Comment: @Yorik exactly! And that's where anybody having the programs, or the OP, could experiment a little and see what happens! If you now put a ≥ (U+2265) and you get a > (U+003E), you will know that it is indeed happening. Otherwise, we could move to another explanation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  solving the problem needs  knowledge of a  specific mapping application and how it's configured in a specific case .That is beyond graphic design skills.

Comment: unfortunate as there still isn't a ton of documentation on the overlap between ArcGIS and Adobe Illustrator. If you search in the GIS Stack Exchange, GeoNet, Adobe Help, the GIS or Illustrator or Graphic Design subreddits on reddit you don't find a lot.